# How to extend native JavaScript types in TypeScript 1.8 using global augmentation?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I'm trying to extend the native JavaScript types using the new global augmentation in TypeScript 1.8 as described [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.8.html). I am however experiencing problems when the extension functions returns the same type.

**Global.ts**

```
export {};
declare global {
    interface Date {
        Copy(): Date;
    }
}

if (!Date.prototype.Copy) {
    Date.prototype.Copy = function () {
        return new Date(this.valueOf());
    };
}
```

**DateHelper.ts**

```
export class DateHelper {
    public static CopyDate(date: Date): Date {
        return date.Copy();
    }
}
```

I'm experiencing the following error TS2322 when trying to use the defined extension in DateHelper.ts:

```
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'Date'.
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Global.ts:

```
interface Date 
{
    Copy: () => Date;
}

Date.prototype.Copy = function() 
{
    return new Date(this.valueOf());
};
```

In your DateHelper.ts

```
import './Global';

export class DateHelper {
    public static CopyDate(date: Date): Date {
        return date.Copy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will actually work, untill you do something like this:

import {Predicate, Selector, Action, Comparer, Dictionary, Group} from 'PrototypeExtensions';

declare global{
 interface Date 
 {
  Copy: () => Date;
 }
}

Date.prototype.Copy = function() 
{
    return new Date(this.valueOf());
};

When you do this you need to add the declare global part, and this in turn gives you the TS2322 error.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this approach until we find a solution utilizing global augmentation.