# How to add static methods to built-in classes?

Tags: typescript, defineproperty, class-extensions

Is there anyhow anyway to add some static method to types like `Date`, `String`, `Array`, etc?

For example I want to add method `today` to `Date` class and in JavaScript I can simply add a property to it or maybe I use Object.defineProperty:

```
Date.today = function(){
    let date = new Date;
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return date;
}
```

---

```
Object.defineProperty(Date, 'today', { get() { ... }});
```

But I didn't find anyway to inform `TypeScript` about this new static member.
Am I missing something or Did I google it the wrong way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910521/how-to-extend-native-javascript-types-in-typescript-1-8-using-global-augmentatio

Comment: @haim770 As I said I'm looking for class extension not prototype.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to augment the `DateConstructor` interface to add static properties:

```
declare global {
    interface DateConstructor {
        today: () => Date
    }
}   

Date.today = function(){
    let date = new Date;
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    return date;
}
```

Similarly extend `StringConstructor` and `ArrayConstructor` for string and arrays. See [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Comment: if you'll be separating the type declaration and implementation. In practice, where do you put the implementing code? and how do you import it?

Comment: @JaimeSangcap You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to define your types in a custom `*.d.ts` file and [configure your `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) to include them.

Comment: thank you for answering. I also found this answer helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/39877446/1730988

Comment: What if the class I'm trying to add a method to is declared as var? Such as 'Response' https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/226dd0b7bf5cb5e5bb4dc34ab0e8e14f408f3e20/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L11554

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to extend Object with static method.
    export class ObjectExtensions { }

```
declare global {
    interface ObjectConstructor {
        safeGet<T>(expresstion: () => T, defaultValue: T): T;
    }
}

Object.safeGet = function <T>(expresstion: () => T, defaultValue: T): T {
    try {
        const value = expresstion();
        if (value != null) return value;

    } catch (e) {
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

In main.ts you have to call this class like this

```
new ObjectExtensions();
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
Object.safeGet<number>(() => data.property.numberProperty);
```

Comment: You can easily use `import`. No need to create extra classes.