# Can I extend `Validators` namespace to include my custom validator implemetation?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to add custom validator for reactive forms. I will do that in form of

```
export class CustomValidators {
  isMemberOf(allowedValues: any[]) {
    return (ctrl: AbstractControl) => {
      //whatever
    };
  }
}
```

How can I declare such method so it would appear as part of existing `Validators` class that is provided with forms module so it will be accessible like `Validators.isMemberOf(...)` just like `Validators.required`

Answer (score 1):

Check [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), it could be helpful to your needs

```
import { Validators } from "your-module";

declare module "your-module" {
    interface Validators {
        isMemberOf(allowedValues: any[]): any;
    }
}

Validators.prototype.isMemberOf = (allowedValues: any[]) => {...}
```

Comment: Close, but my validator is available (even in intellisense) via `Validators.prototype.isMemberOf`. The problem is, that this must be seen as static function. How to do that?

Comment: Or you can augment the constructor as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664732/typescript-how-to-add-static-methods-to-built-in-classes)