# Add static property to builtin type declaration

Tags: typescript

TypeScript's built-in typings are currently missing [`AbortSignal.timeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/timeout). How does one write a `.d.ts` file to add it?

This doesn't work:

```
declare namespace AbortSignal {
  function timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal;
}
```

```
Duplicate identifier 'AbortSignal'.(2300)
lib.dom.d.ts(1984, 11): 'AbortSignal' was also declared here.
lib.dom.d.ts(1996, 13): and here.
```

Comment: Probably [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) is needed.

Comment: The above code is already implicitly global because it's not in a module. If you do the same thing in a module and surround it with `declare global {}`, that doesn't help either.

Comment: Something like that => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664732/typescript-how-to-add-static-methods-to-built-in-classes ?

Comment: That's the idea, but I don't see a straightforward way to do this with `AbortSignal`, because there is no type named `AbortSignalConstructor`. Instead, it's defined like this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.8.4/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L1996-L2000

Comment: Did you try using the latest @types/web ? from: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48003 looks like this is added

Comment: Aaaah, I think use can declare the AbortSignal again. But I can't figure out how the proper way to put new properties to it without override all the others.

Comment: @DerekPollard: Is it possible to do that without changing all the global typings throughout the entire monorepo codebase I'm working on? The latter sounds like it might be a large migration, if there are differences.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TypeScript 4.5+, you can solve this by installing [`@types/web`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/web) as a lib replacement:

```
pnpm add @typescript/lib-dom@npm:@types/web --save-dev
```

```
npm install @typescript/lib-dom@npm:@types/web --save-dev
```

```
yarn add @typescript/lib-dom@npm:@types/web --dev
```

This requires you to have `"dom"` in the [`lib`-section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) of your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this, is to simply redeclare the var again and include the `timeout` property:

```
declare var AbortSignal: {
  prototype: AbortSignal
  new(): AbortSignal
  abort(reason?: any): AbortSignal
  timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal
}
```

This will only work if you also include all the properties that Typescript already knows about. An alternative workaround is to extend the type:

```
type AbortSignalWithTimeout = AbortSignal & { timeout(milliseconds: number): AbortSignal }

const timeoutSignal = (AbortSignal as unknown as AbortSignalWithTimeout).timeout(5000)
```