# When extending the functionality of native Javascript classes, do I need to use this.valueOf()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I am trying to extend the functionality of the String class by creating a subclass called "StringEnhanced" in the following manner.

Below is the code in my `string_enhanced.ts` file.

```
export class StringEnhanced extends String {

    public toKebabCase(): string {
        return this.valueOf()
            .match(/[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)!
            .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
            .join('-');
    }
}
```

**However, I'm unsure if `this.valueOf()` is necessary.**

For example, the following code without `.valueOf()` works no problem as expected.

```
export class StringEnhanced extends String {

    public toKebabCase(): string {
        return this
            .match(/[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)!
            .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
            .join('-');
    }
}
```

**Does it matter if I use `.valueOf()` or not? Are there any reasons for or against using `.valueOf()` when extending other Javascript types like Number and String?**

I first noticed the use of `this.valueOf()` when I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36912555/7489488) regarding a similar topic and wasn't sure why it was being used.

Comment: ohhhhh that makes total sense now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of extending `String`, it makes no difference because `.valueOf()` will just return the primitive type of String.

However, in the case of extending `Date`, `this.valueOf()` will return the primitive type of the Date object, which is a `number` whereas `this`, will return the actual Date object.

Therefore, the answer to the question of whether it matters to use `.valueOf()` or not is, it depends on the type.